# ionic 3 showing content inside iframe, session on persisting inside iframe in iOS

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, session-cookies

I have an iframe page which shows a form which stores data in the session. But once the form is submitted the data from the form is not available as POST and the data which is set in the session is also not available.

Any thoughts?

sample code

```
<ion-content padding>
    <div #frame style="width:100%;height:100%;overflow:scroll !important;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch !important">
        <iframe [src]="adURL | safe : 'resourceUrl'" class="iframe" scrolling="yes" style="width:100%;height:100%;"></iframe>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: If you're talking about sessions, then the Angular equivalent would be using a service. Can you show example code so I can see what exactly your issue is?

Comment: I have added the sample code in the description